# Why can't I access Audio ref in React/Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, audio, react-hooks, next.js, use-ref

I'm using React/Next.js to create an Audio player, but I can't figure out how to get the duration of an audio file. As I understand it, I need to use the `useRef` hook to get access to the HTML Audio element with all the info about the file. Based on other examples I've seen, I should be able to do something like this:

```
const EXAMPLE_TRACK = {
  title: "Track Title",
  src: "http://goldfirestudios.com/proj/howlerjs/sound.ogg"
}

const Track = ({track = EXAMPLE_TRACK}) => {
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);
  const audioRef = useRef(typeof Audio !== "undefined" && new Audio());

  useEffect(() => {
    audioRef.current = new Audio(track.src);
    console.log(audioRef)
    setDuration(audioRef.current.duration);
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <div>Title: {track.title}</div>
      <div>Duration: {duration}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

What's odd here is that I can see the duration is 13 seconds in the console via `console.log(audioRef)`, but when I call `console.log(audioRef.current.duration)`, I get `NaN`. Maybe this has something to do with this being a SSR page, although I thought dropping this code in `useEffect` would make sure this component was mounted in the DOM before executing.

[image: audioRef.current]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case It seems to be related with metadata of the audio not being available when you are calling the `setDuration`.

You can listen for the event `onloadeddata` of the audio API and when this callback is invoked you should receive the correct duration value

```
useEffect(() => {
 audioRef.current = new Audio(track.src);
 audioRef.current.onloadeddata = () => {
   setDuration(audioRef.current.duration);
 };
}, []);
```

Comment: Ah yes, this did the trick!